# Milton.io Authentication

Tags: web, webdav, milton

i have written a small grails webapp. I am using milton.io to access some content via webdav.
So webdav is still working and i am able to put, get, delete files - and so on.
But now i want to add authentication and authorization. And here is the problem:

The Resource Interface gives me 2 methods:

```
Object authenticate(String user, String password);
boolean authorise(Request request, Request.Method method, Auth auth);
```

So my Resource classes implements the Resource Interface, but the method authenticate is never called by the framework. Do i have to implement Auth Basic by my self?

My knowledge about milton is very poor. May be i forgot something, cause my webdav client (e.g. cadaver) never asks for a username / password.

Thanks for any help
Peter Waver

Signature of my Resource Classes:

```
class SResource implements GetableResource, PropFindableResource, Resource, DeletableResource, MoveableResource,  ReportableResource, CopyableResource 

class SFileResource extends SResource implements ReplaceableResource

class SFolderResource extends SResource implements PutableResource, MakeCollectionableResource, CollectionResource
```

And here is the builder to get the HttpManager

```
class SMiltonConfig implements MiltonConfigurator {


protected HttpManagerBuilder builder;
protected List<Initable> initables;
protected HttpManager httpManager;

public SMiltonConfig(){
    try {
        // Attempt to use Enterprise edition build if available
        Class builderClass = Class.forName("io.milton.ent.config.HttpManagerBuilderEnt");
        builder = (HttpManagerBuilder) builderClass.newInstance();
        println ("load Ent. HTTP Manager")
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        builder = new HttpManagerBuilder();
        println ("load Std. HTTP Manager")
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        println ("load Std. HTTP Manager")
        builder = new HttpManagerBuilder();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        println ("load Std. HTTP Manager")
        builder = new HttpManagerBuilder();
    }
}

@Override
public HttpManager configure(Config arg0) throws ServletException {
    ResourceFactory rf = new SResourceFactory();
    builder.setMainResourceFactory(rf);
    checkAddInitable(initables, builder.getMainResourceFactory());
    httpManager = builder.buildHttpManager();
    for( Initable i : initables ) {
        i.init(config, httpManager);
    }
    return httpManager;
}

@Override
public void shutdown() {
    httpManager.shutdown()
    for( Initable i : initables ) {
        i.destroy(httpManager);
    }        
}

private void checkAddInitable(List<Initable> initables, Object o) {
    if( o instanceof Initable) {
        initables.add((Initable)o);
    } else if( o instanceof List ) {
        for( Object o2 : (List)o) {
            checkAddInitable(initables, o2);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here the ResourceFactory

```
class SResourceFactory implements ResourceFactory {

def fileSystemService

public SResourceFactory(){
    println "loading resource Factory"
    def ctx = ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
    fileSystemService = ctx.fileSystemService
}

@Override
public Resource getResource(String host, String strPath)
throws NotAuthorizedException, BadRequestException {
    SResource sfr
    sfr = fileSystemService.getFolderByPath(strPath)
    return sfr
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need Basic Auth - you have to enable it. So add the following line to the config method of the SMiltonConfig Class.

```
builder.setEnableOptionsAuth(true); // enables auth
builder.setEnableBasicAuth(true);   // optional
```

Here'S an example of the Resource authorise Method

```
    @Override
    public boolean authorise(Request r, Method m, Auth a) {
       return a != null;
    }
```

Hope it helps

Florian Pfann